# Nuxt 3 - navigateTo not working after useFetch

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Any idea why this is not working?

I can't redirect after `useFetch`.

```js
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const {slug} = useRoute().params

await useFetch(`http://localhost/${slug}`, {
  async onResponse({response: {_data: data}}) {
    // I'm using google to make sure it's external, but will come from api
    const url = new URL('https://google.com')

    await navigateTo(url.href, {
      external: true
    })
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`navigateTo` doesn't work in the callback function in `useFetch` but only on the very first level of `setup` script

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

const route = useRoute();
const { slug } = route.params;

const { data: post } = await useFetch(`http://localhost/${slug}`);

const { data: url } = await useFetch(`https://google.com`);

navigateTo(url.value.href, {
   external: true
});

</script>
```

Make sure `useFetch()` will return a `Ref` instance, also you don't need async for `navigateTo`.